# how to solve 302 header warning in php linux?

Tags: php, mysql

well, to start my project I gave it chmod -R 777 to my project folder, and when I wanted login on my own return me 302 warning

login function

```
function login(){
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'../controller/login_controller.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:'username='+username+'&password='+password+"&boton=login"
            }).done(function(resp){
                console.log(resp);
                if(resp === 0){
                    $('#error').show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                     reset = $('#username,#password').val('');
                }else if(resp === 1){
                    location.href='../view/home.php';
                }else{  
                    location.href='../view/home.php';
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

**302 error login :**

[image: 302 error login]

how can I solve it?

Comment: 302 is a redirection code.  Do you expect a redirection?

Comment: Can you share your file code here at which page you are getting the 302 status message??

Comment: You see those `location.href` those are also redirections but in JS..!

Answer (score 0):

`302` is not an error.It is merely just a status code for redirection.If you have `Location` header in your code so php will add it automatically.

So **NO WORRIES**

Comment: i have not location header is ajax callings

Comment: What do you mean login is not working??? You may be getting some error etc anything at all?